# Which instance of data was selected on windows 8 grid app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, microsoft-metro

So I have an app which has some data with a many-many relationship. A diary can have multiple entries in it and each entry can belong to multiple diaries. This displays in the grid app nicely:

[image]

So as you can see from the image above 1 entry can be in more than one diary.

This works fine, but when they click on an entry it fires off an event where I am able to get the object associated with the specific tile, but not which group it is in. I need to be able to know which diary the entry they click on came from so that you can go left/right between each entry in that specific diary.

So when they click on an entry tile (eg "Memory 1 Title" tile in the image above) the following event is fired off:

```
/// <summary>
/// Invoked when an item is clicked.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The GridView (or ListView when the application is snapped)
/// displaying the item clicked.</param>
/// <param name="e">Event data that describes the item clicked.</param>
void ItemView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Navigate to the appropriate destination page, configuring the new page
    // by passing required information as a navigation parameter
}
```

And I can get the object by doing `e.ClickedItem` but I am unable to see which group the item was in which they clicked. Would anybody be able to help me figure this one out?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you not able to look through the parent objects of the clicked item until you get to a group?

Comment: Not that I can see, I've used the debugger to try and find something I can use but have had no luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious way to do it. One idea is to have your dataobject in the grid reference the group, then cast the e.ClickedItem to your dataobject type and access the group via the reference.

Comment: Would you know how to go about doing this using XAML? I'm not really sure about how the XAML works 100%, I just managed to get it to do what I want using the Grid App example that Visual Studio 2012 makes for you.